# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping Problem

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm fairly new to nhibernate and fluent nhibernate, I have an issue with associating a collection to a query.  In the database I have a well and have 4 associated AFEs.  The problem I'm having is that the collection of AFEs is not populating correctly.  No matter what I do, I get 4 AFEs in the collection but they are all the same object. Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong.

Thanks

PS.  I don't have change access to the database that I'm hitting so I can't change the db to make this a true FK.

Parent

```
    public WellHeaderMap()
    {
        Table("Well");
        Id(x => x.PropertyNumber, "WELL_NUMBER");
        Map(x => x.PropertyID, "PROPERTY_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "WELL_NAME");

        //AFEs is a IList<AFE>
        HasMany(x => x.AFEs).Inverse().KeyColumn("Property_ID").PropertyRef("PropertyID").Fetch.Join();
    }
```

Collection

```
    public AFEMap()
    {
        Table("AFE");
        Id(x => x.PropertyID, "PROPERTY_ID");
        Map(x => x.AFETypeID, "AFE_TYPE_CODE");
        Map(x => x.AFENumber, "AFE_NUMBER");
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted, "DELETED_IND");
    }
```

Query

```
        var wellSearchCriteria = _session.CreateCriteria<WellHeader>()
            .CreateAlias("AFEs", "afe")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("PropertyNumber", id.ToString()))
            //.Add(Expression.Eq("afe.AFETypeID", "01"))
            //.Add(Expression.Eq("afe.IsDeleted", "N"));
```

Comment: Does wellHeader.AFEs return the same 4 entities?

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing your table structure, class structure and mappings. Are you sure you want the `HasMany` to be inverted to a `many-to-one`? I don't see a property referencing back to the parent to support this relationship.

Comment: Yes, wellHeader.AFEs always returns the same 4.  Even if I add uncomment the afe in the query,  I should only return 1 AFE, but it still returns 4.  I think I threw the inverse on there just because of a sample I found.  Same result if I leave the inverse off.

Comment: You could check to see if these 4 are actually the same reference and remove them by using .Distinct() on your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have your WellHeader Id wrong, currently you have:

```
Id(x => x.PropertyNumber, "WELL_NUMBER");
Map(x => x.PropertyID, "PROPERTY_ID");
```

Probably should be:

```
Id(x => x.PropertyID, "PROPERTY_ID");
Map(x => x.PropertyNumber, "WELL_NUMBER");
```

The PropertyNumber and PropertyId were switched. However without seeing your schema, its hard to tell.

Comment: technically, it's not a primary key on the table itself, I was just arbitrarily setting the Id to assist with mapping to some of my own tables.

Comment: If PropertyID is not a PK, is it possible you have multiple Wells in the with the same PROPERTY_ID?

Comment: There is a unique constraint on PROPERTY_ID, and i did a query just to make sure and there are no property ids repeated.

Comment: yes, it also unique.  I know, I know, if I would have created the database, I would have done it different.  That's the joy of vendored applications :)

Comment: Can you try swapping the two around like shown in my answer, just as a quick test?

Comment: Then see if WellHeader.AFEs returns the same 4. Leaving your query out of the picture.

Comment: Same result,  I had to take off the PropertyRef("PropertyID") (Got a "could not resolve property: AFEs of: Domain.WellHeader" QueryException.  But I still get the same 4.